# Combine git log --stat with --name-status?

Tags: git

I have two `git log` aliases set up: one to show `--name-status`:

```
...
| A   path/to/yourfile.c
| M   path/to/myfile.c
| M   path/to/my/otherfile.c
...
```

and one to show `--stat`:

```
...
|  path/to/yourfile.c          |    2 ++
|  path/to/myfile.c            |    2 +-
|  path/to/my/otherfile.c      |   27 +++++-----
...
```

Is it possible to combine the two?

```
...
| A   path/to/yourfile.c          |    2 ++
| M   path/to/myfile.c            |    2 +-
| M   path/to/my/otherfile.c      |   27 +++++-----
...
```

I love the `--stat` overview, but it doesn't tell me if files were added or removed; just that they were modified in some way.

(When the two command-line flags are combined, `--stat` is ignored.)

Answer (score 7):

I don't know of a way to combine `--stat` and `--name-status`, but you can use `git log --stat --summary` to get a list of added/removed/renamed/copied files in addition to the diffstat.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar idea for `git status` and `git diff --stat`.  Someone helped me come up with:

```
git status | sed -e "$(git diff --stat | sed -e 's#/#\\/#g' | awk '/\|/ {print "s/" $1 "/" $0 "/;"}')"
```

I tried to replace it with your git log commands but they are too long (due to it being paged).  If you shorten your log with `-n5` (only show the last 5 commits) it's a good start

```
git log --name-only -n5| sed -e "$(git log --stat -n5 | sed -e 's#/#\\/#g' | awk '/\|/ {print "s/" $1 "/" $0 "/;"}')"
```